# Different intervals between images

Tags: javascript, arrays, dreamweaver, intervals

I am studying for GCSE computing and need to be able to change the interval between different images. My code at the moment looks something like this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Traffic lights can change on their own </h1>

<img src="RED.jpg" id= "traffic" width="155" height="198">
<script>

var myImage = document.getElementById("traffic");

 var imageArray = ["RED.jpg", "RED-ORANGE.jpg", "GREEN.jpg", "ORANGE.jpg"];

 var imageIndex = 0; 

 function changeImage() 
{
  myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
 }

}

setInterval(changeImage,1000);

</script>
</body>
</html>+
```

If you could include some of this code whilst changing the intervals that would be ideal.

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: I need different intervals between 5 different images. And at the moment I don't have a code that will change the interval.

Comment: stackoverflow is a forum for discussing programming problems, not for someone else to implement anything for you...

Comment: Well I do have a problem that I need solving. That is different intervals between images. @Bonatti

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to solve this using Javascript only:

> [Source documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

```
// Save the var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, [delay]);
var imageTimers = [500, 1000, 2000, 4000];
var timeTochange = Math.random() * 3000; // or whatever you want to use...
var aTimer = setTimeout(changeImage, timeTochange);

// On the changeImage, alter the timeTochange var.
function changeImage() {
   // ...stuffs...
   clearTimeout(aTimer);
   timeTochange = imageTimers[imageIndex];
   aTimer = setTimeout(changeImage, timeTochange);
}
```